# Click button only works with browser zoom in 100% but not with other zoom setting (like 90%, 80%, 70%)

Tags: python, selenium

I want to press a button (next page) and it works only when the browser is with 100% zoom. For some other issues I want to run my script with the browser in 25% zoom but when I do it, the script just don’t press the button anymore, it shows no errors, nothing, just nothing happens. I really don’t know what is causing this ¿does anybody knows how to fix this?

This is how I press the button (works with 100% zoom but not with 25%):

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class='my_class']").click()
```

The web site is heavy on java if helps.

Thank you very much!

Comment: That sounds very unlikely. Can you provide a concrete [mcve]?

Comment: I know, it does not make any sense :( 

Going to try to create de example. Thanks!